# Symfony 2 CMF: Embed content twig in another admin twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata-admin, symfony-cmf

I have created a twig file in sonata admin, where I want to show the preview of the another twig created  using the sonata cms.

I found the use of **render** method to embed the controller action.

```
<div class="preview">
                        {{ render(controller('Bundle:Controller:action') }}
</div>
```

But the action takes an argument $contentDocument

```
public function Action($contentDocument, Request $request)
{
}
```

So how do I render this twig inside the preview div, to show a thumbnail to the user.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters as a second parameter to the controller() twig function:
{{ render(controller('Bundle:Controller:action', {'contentDocument': some_instance_of_a_content_document}) }}

Comment: I tried that, the problem is how can I get the handle of the instance of the content document in the twig? Any suggestions?

Comment: You can fetch a document from the repository inside twig. the relevant methods are part of the CoreBundle: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/core/templating.html

Comment: note that if you intend to use the render(controller()) for ESI, there will be a sub request and you can't share the request context (and also can't pass objects, only scalar values). then you would need to pass the *id* of that content document and load it in the controller.